# CityHash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I'm looking to use CityHash64 from Javascript. I found [this node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cityhash) but I can't figure out how to make it independent of node, is this possible?

My intention is to use it from a webrowser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE) addon.

Comment: You're looking for Browserify.  Except that that's C++, so you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks is Browserify the only way to get node.js module to work independent of node?

Comment: The module says it has no dependencies. Have you tried downloading the code and checking the source? If it's as small as other (non-crypto) hash function implementations I've seen, it shouldn't be too hard to just copy/paste out the parts you need. The package is MIT license, so you should just need to attribute it in your source (I am not a lawyer).

Comment: @PatrickM: [The module is written in C++](https://github.com/fbzhong/node-cityhash), so there is no JS to copy & paste.

Comment: CityHash uses 64-bit arithmetic which means even if you ported it to JS, emulating 64-bit operations would decrease performance by 80%. Use MurmurHash3_x86_128 or lookup3. for fast 128-bit or 64-bit hashes in JS.

Comment: @bryc thanks for that note on perf reduction. I needed it regardless of pref. I had to match an encrypted string that was encrypted on the native side using C++.

Comment: @Noitidart If still needed, look into new WebAssembly API which has good 64-bit perf. No CityHash port yet, but it's only matter of time. There is [FarmHash](https://github.com/cjihrig/farmhash.wasm) and [xxHash](https://github.com/jungomi/xxhash-wasm) implementations already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MurmurHash instead.

https://github.com/garycourt/murmurhash-js

CityHash has higher throughput and is more complex, MurmurHash has lower latency for very short keys and is relatively simple.
Both are more than adequate for any sort of hashing needs you might have.